# CodeceptionでAspectMock を使ってメソッドの変数を固定できる方法はありますか？

Tags: php, laravel, テスト

下記のテストで`User::where`で`test::double`を使っての返り値の固定ができませんでした。

Model

```php
class User extends Model
{
  public static function isEmailExist($email)
  {
      if ( ! isset($email)) return false;
      $hit = (int)User::where('email', $email)->count();
      if ($hit > 0) {
          return true;
      }
      return false;
  }
}
```

unitTest

```php
<?php
require_once __DIR__.'/../../app/User.php';
use \AspectMock\Test as test;

class UserTest extends \Codeception\TestCase\Test
{
  /**
   * @var \UnitTester
   */
  protected $model;

  protected function _before()
  {
  }

  protected function _after()
  {
  }

  public function testisEmailExist()
  {
      $emailInstance = test::double('\App\User')->make();
      $emailInstanceProxy = test::double($emailInstance, ['count' => 1]);
      $emailClassProxy = test::double('\App\User', ['where' => $emailInstance]);
      $user = new \App\User();
      $this->assertEquals(true, $user->isEmailExist('test@co.jp'));
  }
}
```

この他にもいろいろ試しましたができません。
返り値の固定方法を知っている方はいますか？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

こんにちは。

```
User::where('email', $email)->count();
```

この`count`の結果を固定したい、ということだと思いますので、

```
    public function testisEmailExist()
    {
        test::double('Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder', ['count' => 1]);
        $user = new \App\User();
        $this->assertEquals(true, $user->isEmailExist('test@co.jp'));
    }
```

でうまくいかないでしょうか？
（`User::where`の戻り値の型は`Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder`になるため、その`count`をスタブ化します）

---

手元では以下の前提で期待通りに動きましたので、ご参考ください。
（ご質問の内容からLaravel5, Codeception2.xと判断しました。）

### 前提環境

- Laravel v5.0.33
- Codeception 2.1.2
- AspectMock 0.5.3

### tests/unit.suite.yml

```
class_name: UnitTester
modules:
enabled:
    - Asserts
    - \Helper\Unit
    - Laravel5
```

### tests/unit/bootstrap.php

```
<?php
$kernel = \AspectMock\Kernel::getInstance();
$kernel->init([
    'appDir' => __DIR__ . '/../../app',
]);
```

Comment: 私の環境は2.0.0でしたが解決することができました！
ありがとうございます！